# Python Index Error - Out of Bounds for axis 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataset like the following in the txt file. (First column is=userid, second column is=locationid)
Normally my dataset is big but I created a dummy dataset to better explain my problem.

I'm trying to create a matrix like in the code below. row will be userid column location id. Since this dataset shows the location ids visited by the users, I assign the value 1 in the code to the locations they visited in the matrix.

I am getting an indexerror.`IndexError: index 801 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50`

I tried different user_num and poi_num but still doesn't work

**datausers.txt**

```
801 32332
801 14470
801 33847
501 10259
501 34041
501 10201
301 15810
301 34827
301 19264
401 34834
401 35407
401 36115
```

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd 

train_file = "datausers.txt"
user_num = 20
poi_num = 20

training_matrix = np.zeros((user_num, poi_num))
train_data = list(islice(open(train_file, 'r'), 10))

for eachline in train_data:
    uid, lid= eachline.strip().split()
    uid, lid = int(uid), int(lid)
    training_matrix[uid, lid] = 1.0
```

**Error**

[image]

**Expected Output**

4x12 Matrix because we have 4 unique users and 12 unique location

```
[1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
]
```

For example for first row
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

User 801 visited 3 locations and those are 1. (The location of the 1's can be variable I gave it to be an example)

Comment: What is the expected output? Is there a specific reason why don't you just use `uid, lid = np.loadtxt(train_file, delimiter=" ", unpack=True)`?

Comment: `training_matrix[uid, lid] = 1.0` this line won't work, because `uid` is 801, and `lid` is 32332, and you created `training_matrix` as 20x20. Instead, you should make some kind of  mapping.

Comment: I added what I expected as a result. I am changing to a 1000 x 1000 matrix. Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't understand what is "you should make some kind of mapping." mean

Comment: In your example, your user ids range from 401 to 801. This means you have to encode these values somehow, because matrix indices start from 0. Same goes for location id.  A possible (and not so good) workaround is: align the matrix size for the maximum values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have tagged the question with `pandas`, here is one way of approaching the problem with `str.get_dummies` method of the pandas `Series`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('datausers.txt', sep='\s+', names=['userid', 'locationid'], index_col=0)
out = df['locationid'].astype(str).str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

**Result**

For the sample data

```
>>> out
        10201  10259  14470  15810  19264  32332  33847  34041  34827  34834  35407  36115
userid                                                                                    
801         0      0      1      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0
501         1      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
301         0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
401         0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1
```

If you need `numpy` array instead:

```
>>> out.to_numpy()

array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, I actually chose a harder way to solve it. Your solution is pretty cool. Thank you very much!

Comment: @drorhun Glad i could help!

Comment: How can I reach the data by using "out." I am trying to out[801] => it is not giving me the first row.

Comment: out[0:1] is working but I need to reach by using userid.

Comment: @drorhun You can reference by `userid` and `locationid` in the dataframe using the `loc` attribute but you couldn't be able to do that in the `numpy` array because its is `zero` indexed..I suggest to you work with the dataframe instead of numpy array..For example in dataframe you could do `df.loc[801, '10201']` to select the location of userid `801`.